# using async/await insted of AJAX

Tags: javascript, jsp, async-await

I am going to use async await instead of AJAX in jsp file. How can I use async/await? This is my code:

```
function setAcc(){
    var acc_ = getDOM("acc_").value
    AJAX.load({POST: {request: 'set_acc', async: false, acc_: acc_},
        onSuccess: function (result) {
            var objJSON = eval("(function(){return " + result + ";})()");
        go({});
        },
        onError: function (d) {
            alert_g(eval(d));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Use `JSON.parse(result)` instead of `eval()` for parsing JSON.

Comment: how can I send my post request with async await?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Instead of ajax you should use axios library for that and then use async and await accordingly for the Server request's.

Try this link for more understanding

- [async await using axios](https://www.better.dev/asynchronous-javascript-using-async-await)